# display separate array in sql php

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have one question about my database.

**table inventory**

```
_______________________________________
id_item | item_name  | quantity |price |
--------+------------+----------+------+
1       | brake      | 20       |60    |
--------+------------+----------+------+
2       | oil filter | 20       |80    |
--------+------------+----------+------+
```

**table invoice**

```
______________________________
id_invoice | items | quantity |
-----------+-------+----------+ 
1          | 1,2   | 4, 1     |
-----------+-------+----------+
```

So I'm going to display back items in a table as an invoice ( view purpose )

but I'm stucked at how to explode/ display it using SQL.

I mean I want to display it like this:

**table html**

```
_________________________________________
No |    item    | quantity | total price |
---+------------+----------+-------------+
1  | brake      | 4        | 240         |
---+------------+----------+-------------+
2  | oil filter | 1        | 80          |
---+------------+----------+-------------+
```

I just need a simple code to make this function. I only left this function to complete my system.

Thank you!

Comment: Whats the different between quantity in inventory table and quantity in invoice table? Where is your primary key and foreignkey stored? Give a example. A simple join should do it.

Comment: quantity in inventory : stock for items
quantity in invoice : quantity item that user bought/purchased

Comment: Where is your code? You can not ask us to build it. Try it, and back to us if find any errors or problems.

Comment: Refactor your invoice table to only store a single item per line. Now you are building nasty workarounds for a bad database design.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider how can i store a single item per line ? so if i have 5 items in one invoice, then it will will be 5 lines for 5 items but invoice id is same ?

Comment: @AminAzhar exactly, that's how it is usually done.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps : (dont have the patience to write the code for you right now, I am a PHP beginner too)..

1. Get the list of Invoice items by a select query on invoice table with the invoice number criteria.
2. Since your items and comma-separated in the database, get the quantity(list) field into a string variable.
3. Apply the `explode` function on the quantity(list) variable and get the output into an array.
4. Loop through the `array` and build the html rows. If you want a quick and generic function to do this, and if you know how PHP functions work, you can use readymade code [html_show_array from here](https://github.com/jmiskiewicz/home/blob/master/@work/php/html_show_array.php) to accomplish this step.